# Nested serializer data in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 django models like this

**To keep record of orders**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**which articles are in order**   like pizza etc

```
class OrderArticle(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Article options of articles in order (like topping on pizza , now topping can be 4 or more types)**

```
class OrderArticleOptions(models.Model):
    article_option = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_article = models.ForeignKey(OrderArticle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

To keep track of this multipul type of Article options I made this table . So example will be . ***Customer purchased a pizza with 2 toppings , 1st topping fajita quantiity is 1 and 2nd topping oliva quantity is 3 .***

to get this use case using Django Rest framework what should I do ?

**Issue**

I want data like this

data {

```
orders[

 article1
     {
      articleoptio1
       {}
      articleoption2
       {}        
      }
```

]

}

Now issue is when I add 2 type of toppings to a single article in order, it creates 2 diff orders with 2 articles with each article option. While I want 1 article with 2 article options .

Comment: Maybe this can help you [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski  kindly have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ArticlesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = "__all__"


class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    articles = ArticlesSerializer(source="resturant.article", many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"
```

Ok here I am using nested serializer, with key, "source". "source" is a little bit advanced concept I am sorry for using that, but I can't see any other optimal way. You can call the serializer from your views.

If you want to see learn more about nested serializers, I recommend you see the tutorial,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAJAC_P52VU

Comment: there is a sequence , first   Orders - >  Articles -> Article Options . you are just saying like this  Orders - >  Articles

Comment: Yes you have to keep in mind the sequence of your foreign keys. if you want to create Orders - > Articles -> Article Options. Create a serializer for Article Options and nest it inside the Articles Serializer, but again be mindful of the sequence of models(Foreign keys).

Answer (score 0):

Try Nested Serializers, It will solve your problem. See the nested serializer docs.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects